# jquery let user type 3 chars then disable editing textfield and select from autocomplete instead

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, edit

Im trying with jquery to advanche an auto-complete textfield.

- user types 3 chars
- the cities gets loaded into a drop down ( with ajax autocomplete )

Now I would like to:

- Prevent the user from manually enter there city name but instead choose it from the drop down list. Is there a good way to do this? I have searched and searched but not found a good solution because the user at first have to be able to type a few chars in the textfield, for the autocomplete to be triggered.

My function so far wich works (it returns only city_name for now):

```
  $("#user_profile_attributes_city_id").autocomplete({
    source: "/data/living",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);
      $(this).find("#country_id").val(ui.item.country_id);
      $(this).find("#city_id").val(ui.item.city_id);
      event.preventDefault;
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put autocomplete initially,

```
 <input autocomplete="off" />
```

Actually you chould put some validation on FORM submission if the value is in a list you wanted.

```
 $('form#id').submit(function(){

//validate
if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
    return false;
}
if ( $(this).val()  is_in_list ) {
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#element').bind('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 3) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    // ajax-call
  }
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPPnP/)

Answer (score 1):

You can tap into the 'open' and 'close' events of autocomplete to achive this.
Check the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)